# Confirmed Bug: Why does Eliminate fail while Solve succeeds?

Tags: equation-solving, bugs

OP EDIT:  Wolfram Technical Support got back to me and confirmed this is a bug. But the Answers below provided good workarounds.

I have two polynomials respectively in {z,c} and in {r,z,c}. I'd like to eliminate z and get a tidy expression in {r,c}.  For some reason, Eliminate[] never completes this simple task, while Solve[] quickly succeeds at the harder task of finding r as a function of c.  But the Solve[] result is messy, so I'd like to know how to get just Eliminate[] to work.

Edit: I believe the solution should be a fairly simply polynomial in {r,c}.

The first three lines of code just generate and display my two polynomials.

```
w[n_, z_, c_] := If[n > 0, w[n - 1, z, c]^2 + c, z]; 
p1 = PolynomialQuotient[w[4, z, c] - z, w[2, z, c] - z, z]
p2 = 2^4; Do[p2 = p2*w[i, z, c], {i, 0, 3}]; p2
Solve[{p1 == 0, p2 == r}, r, {z}]
Eliminate[{p1 == 0, p2 == r}, {z}]
```

Comment: Are you looking for real solutions?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann  No, all of the variables are complex.  I'm hoping for a polynomial in {r,c} simpler than the expression for r(c) that Solve[] returned.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure what the hang-up for `Eliminate[]` is.  This is fast:

```
GroebnerBasis[{p1, p2 - r}, {c, r}, {z}]
(*
  {4096 + 8192 c^2 + 12288 c^3 + 12288 c^4 + 12288 c^5 + 4096 c^6 - 
    768 r - 256 c^2 r + 256 c^3 r + 256 c^4 r + 48 r^2 - 16 c^2 r^2 - r^3}
*)
```

Comment: Yep, that does exactly what I wanted. Thank you.  I didn't know that function existed.  Do more current versions of MMa also hang up when you use Eliminate[]?  Might this be a bug?

Comment: @JerryGuern I'm using V12 and it hangs.  I don't know about other versions.

Comment: Wolfram Tech Support confirmed it's a bug in Eliminate[], but this workaround was perfect.

Answer (score 5):

I offer the following approach.  Let

```
soln = Solve[{p1 == 0, p2 == r}, r, {z}]
```

Then find the polynomial that has these roots:

```
0 == Times @@ ((r - Last[#]) & /@ Flatten[soln]) // 
 Collect[#, r, Simplify] &
(* 0 == -4096 (1 + 2 c^2 + 3 c^3 + 3 c^4 + 3 c^5 + c^6) - 
  256 (-3 - c^2 + c^3 + c^4) r + 16 (-3 + c^2) r^2 + r^3 *)
```

Comment: A bit ghetto but clever and effective!  Thank you.  I'd still like to know what's wrong with Eliminate[] though.

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to solve for r!

Elimination of z:

```
solz== Solve[p2 == 0, z]
(*{{z -> 0}, {z -> -Sqrt[-Sqrt[-Sqrt[-c] - c] - c]}, {z -> Sqrt[-Sqrt[-Sqrt[-c] - c] - c]}, ...}*)
```

gives 15 solutions `z[c]`

Complex Solutions (15! ) `r[c]` follow  to

```
r=p1 /. solz // FullSimplify
(*{1 + c^2 (1 + c) (2 + c) (1 + c^2),1 + Sqrt[-Sqrt[-Sqrt[-c] - c] - c] Sqrt[-Sqrt[-c] - c] +Sqrt[-Sqrt[-c] - c] Sqrt[-c], 
1 - Sqrt[-Sqrt[-Sqrt[-c] - c] - c] Sqrt[-Sqrt[-c] - c] +Sqrt[-Sqrt[-c] - c] Sqrt[-c],...*)
```

Perhaps the first result is the simple polynomial solution you're looking for!

Further evaluation needs knowledge about parameter c!

Comment: No, p2 has to equal r.

Comment: Sorry, my fault...